# Encountering this error "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/initrd.img'" in reactJS when i import BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Multiple people ([like asked here](https://Error:%20ENOENT:%20no%20such%20file%20or%20directory,%20stat%20%27/initrd.img%27)) have asked the same question but I couldn't resolve my problem as almost all the solutions asked me to check for mistakes while importing but I am sure I went through all of them but couldn't find anyone that made sense to me. My code used to be much bigger but as someone mentioned in the solution to the post I have tagged previously, I created a new app using CRA and imported things one by one only to realize that this error started appearing as soon as I imported the routing method as mentioned in my code.
I am aware that this error is pointing to the broken symlinks in my system as mentioned in some other posts(also pointed to another symlink when I previously ran my code) but I am trying to find a way to resolve this without damaging my system by deleting symlinks.
After using CRA to make a new app I tried to run this code which worked fine until I imported Router.

**edit: As soon as I removed routing from my initial project (which had multiple components ) it got fixed. I need to figure out a way to route this now.**

My index.js CODE :

```
import React from 'react'; 
import {render} from 'react-dom'; 
import App from './App';  
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from'react-router-dom';
render(    
    <Router>
         <App />   
    </Router>,  
     document.getElementById('root') );
```

My App.js CODE :

```
import React from "react";

function App()
{
  return(
     <h1>  hello world  </h1> 
  )
}

export default App;
```

PS: Thank you for reading my post, please post your solutions or links that might help.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing `@material-ui/icons`

Try to install it

```
npm install @material-ui/icons
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case an `import` statement was missing a file. Check your import statements. It actually shows what's missing for a second on the `Compiling...` screen after `npm start`